# separate NaN text columns into other dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have two columns X and Y which are text columns. X is my feature and Y is my target variable. My Y variable consists of `NaN` values. I want to separate `NaN` values of Y into a separate data frame so that I will use them in my test dataset.

```
   Y
1. aaa
2. bbb
3. ccc
4. NaN
5. NaN
6. ddd
```

Could anyone tell me how to separate the NaN rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isna.html):

```
mask = df['Y'].isna()
#oldier pandas versions
#mask = df['Y'].isnull()
#DataFrame with NaNs
df1 = df[mask]
#DataFrame with no NaNs
df2 = df[~mask]
```